# How to get Cloud SQL events?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I would like to be able to trigger a HTTP request to my server whenever my Cloud SQL instance reaches 90% CPU utilization or 80% memory utilization.

**Can I setup a cloud event that triggers an HTTP request when this occurs? If not, at the very least, can I write a script that polls my Cloud SQL instance via API? If so, what endpoint returns the status of my instance?**

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud SQL supports metrics and monitoring. CPU usage is a supported metric. Calling a webhook is a supported notification channel.

AFAIK there is no endpoint for you to call to fetch metrics.

[Cloud SQL Available Metrics](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/monitor-instance#available-metrics)

[Google Cloud Notification Channles - Webhook](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#webhooks)

[Introduction to alerting](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts)